# The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCaZD.png)

getting error as shown in message ( The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)

error should be gone if buildpath is correct

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do below mentioned steps to resolve this issue.
click on below steps to see image

1. [right click on project>BuildPath>Configure Buildpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUpdN.png)
2. [in java build path > Libraries > JRE System Library > Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDjx5.png)
3. [click Workspace Default JRE > click finish > Click apply and close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YP1q.png)